# Convert SQL Query into LINQ Expression - LIKE operator on integer

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Can someone convert the following simple SQL statement into LINQ?  The StudentID is of type int.

select * from Student where studentId  like '%1001%';

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ctx.Student.Where(x => x.StudentId.Contains("1001"))
```

It's strange that you have an ID of string type. 
Use int instead.

O, sorry, I see now, you wrote that ids are ints. In that case you cannot use like in SQL.
It doesnt make sense. You must convert int to string first.

```
ctx.Student.Where(x => x.StudentId.ToString().Contains("1001"))
```

Comment: It works! I tried this before and it did not work because I forgot to use quotes in "1001".  Thank you so much for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Contains operator:

```
from s in Student
where s.studentId.ToString().Contains("1001")
select s;
```

Comment: It is giving the following error: 'int' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, TSource)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Change it to:  where s.studentId.ToString().Contains("1001")  I was assuming since you were comparing a column to a string in your original query that the column itself was a string.
Honestly, this sort of query goes against what I would consider good programming practices with regards to the use of primary keys; it makes me think that there may be a better way to accomplish what you want that will give you less headaches down the road.  You may want to investigate.

Comment: Just reread the OP and noticed that it stated that it was an int, my bad.

Comment: Actually, the StudentID column is of type int.  I wanted to return all rows that matches 1001.  I belive this is the only simple way you can retrieve all rows that contains 1001.  Let me know if my understanding is wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db.Students.Where(s => s.StudentID.ToString().Contains("1001"))
```