# Using contains on an integer in LINQ to SQL

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

I'm trying the following query:

```
Return _context.companies _
        .Where(Function(c) c.id.StartsWith(filterCompanyId)) _
    .ToList()
```

but because `id` is an integer, it doesn't work. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6460981/1406664) which suggests I can use

```
c.id.ToString().StartsWith ...
```

but that gives me the following error:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

When trying to use

```
.Where(Function(c) SqlFunctions.StringConvert(CDbl(c.id)).StartsWith("1"))
```

it doesn't work.

Any tips?

Comment: So if `filterCompanyId` is `3`, you want to return all companies `3`, `31`, `302`, etc. Is that really correct? Does that make sense?

Comment: What error message do you get on your second attempt?

Comment: Yes that's correct. The users are familiar with the IDs and find it easy to type the company id into a box to quickly get there.

Comment: This should help for your conversion to string: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1066760/87698

Comment: I found that post but couldn't get it working with VB.net/my version of EF.

Comment: What problems did you encounter? What happens if you just use `SqlFunctions.StringConvert(CDbl(c.id)).StartsWith`?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717253/how-do-i-query-an-integer-column-for-starts-with-in-entity-framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @Heinzi's comment, StringConvert is not supported by the MySQL-EF-Provider. I ended up going with a query string:

```
Dim isExpiredInt As Integer = If(isExpired, 1, 0)

Dim query As String = "Select * FROM company WHERE (expired = 0 OR expired = {0}) AND name like {1} AND id like {2}"

Dim companies = _context.ExecuteStoreQuery(Of company)(
    query,
    "companies",
    System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.AppendOnly,
    isExpiredInt, "%" & filterCompanyName & "%", filterCompanyId & "%"
).ToList()

Return companies
```

Note the `System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.AppendOnly` is something I added so the objects from this query would be attached to my context (i.e. calling `SaveChanges` on this context would write to the database).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

The relevant part is hidden in the error message:

> 'SqlFunctions' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level

`SqlFunctions` is in the `System.Data.Objects.SqlClient` namespace (you can discover this by going to the ["SqlFunctions Class" MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then checking the "Namespace:" entry). Thus, you need to import that namespace at the top of your code file:

```
Imports System.Data.Objects.SqlClient
```

Comment: @SamSelikoff: Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: Nope, I'm using MySQL

Comment: @SamSelikoff: Oh, that explains it. Unfortunately, StringConvert is not supported by the MySQL-EF-Provider, so you might have to [use good old SQL instead](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4275700/87698).